# What's the different when build a project through the msbuild and dotnet on jenkins?

Tags: c#, jenkins, .net-core, build, msbuild

When i make a proj in vs 2019 by using .net core 3.1, and it will all be ok when both build in cmd using msBuild or dotnet and also the nunit3-console.exe test for that proj is also success, but when i using them in jenkins, the msbuild cmd can build ok,but it will failed for nunit3-console.exe Testing  (**both of them is build a .sln file**)

[this is a dotnetBuild and then run nunit test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXYiS.jpg)
[this is a msbuild and then run nunit test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hFDX.jpg)
[this is a config for my proj](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXKmC.jpg)

```
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace TestProject1
{
    public class Tests
    {
        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test1()
        {
            Assert.Pass();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [`dotnet test`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test)? Please also note that .NET Core 3.1 is end-of-life

Comment: dotnet test is also failed when build in jenkins using msbuild, but if using dotent build then test(whatevery `dotnet test` or `nunit3-console.exe Testing`) is both work

Comment: And when using `dotnet msbuild YourSolution.sln`?

Comment: If it build by msbuild in jenkins and then using that make error,
but if open vs to clean the Solution.sln, and then make this in jenkins and then test is ok.